# Bootstrap 3 navbar centering menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the following html for my main menu.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
           <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header" style="margin:0;">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home"  href="#"><img src="//<?=SITEURL;?>/templates/harrower/images/logo.png" alt="Harrower.XYZ"></a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <?php
                    foreach($menu as $item){
                      if(empty($item['submenu'])){
                        if(MongoId::isValid ($item['task']) == 1)
                        {
                          $link = self::fetch_link($item['task']);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                          $link = array();
                          $link['url'] = $item['task'];
                        }
                      ?>
                        <li <?php if('URI_1' == $link['url']){echo 'class="active"';}?>><a href="//<?=SITEURL;?>/<?=$link['url'];?>"><?=$item['title'];?></a></li>
                      <?php
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        if(MongoId::isValid ($item['task']) == 1)
                        {
                          $link = self::fetch_link($item['task']);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                          $link = array();
                          $link['url'] = $item['task'];
                        }
                      ?>
                            <li class="dropdown
                            <?php if(URI_1 == $link){
                               echo ' active';
                            }?>
                            ">
                              <a href="//<?=SITEURL;?>/<?=$link['url'];?>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><?=$item['title'];?><span class="caret"></span></a>
                                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <?php
                                          foreach($item['submenu'] as $submenu)
                                          {
                                            if(MongoId::isValid ($submenu['task']) == 1)
                                            {
                                              $link = self::fetch_link($submenu['task']);
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                            $link = array();
                                            $link['url'] = $submenu['task'];
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                            <li
                                            <?php
                                            if(URI_1 == $link){
                                               echo 'class="active"';
                                            }

                                            echo '><a href="//'; print SITEURL."/".$link['url']; echo'">';
                                            print $submenu['title'];
                                            echo '</a></li>';

                                          }
                                    ?>
                                    </ul>
                            </li>
                        <?php
                      }
                    }
                    ?>

                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills navbar-right" id="socialnetwork">
                  <li><a href="#"><div class="socialnetwork youtube"></div></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><div class="socialnetwork twitter"></div></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><div class="socialnetwork facebook"></div></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><div class="socialnetwork gplus"></div></a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        </nav>
```

Now I wanted the main menu UL (code below) to be centered.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <?php
                        foreach($menu as $item){
                          if(empty($item['submenu'])){
                            if(MongoId::isValid ($item['task']) == 1)
                            {
                              $link = self::fetch_link($item['task']);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                              $link = array();
                              $link['url'] = $item['task'];
                            }
                          ?>
                            <li <?php if('URI_1' == $link['url']){echo 'class="active"';}?>><a href="//<?=SITEURL;?>/<?=$link['url'];?>"><?=$item['title'];?></a></li>
                          <?php
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            if(MongoId::isValid ($item['task']) == 1)
                            {
                              $link = self::fetch_link($item['task']);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                              $link = array();
                              $link['url'] = $item['task'];
                            }
                          ?>
                                <li class="dropdown
                                <?php if(URI_1 == $link){
                                   echo ' active';
                                }?>
                                ">
                                  <a href="//<?=SITEURL;?>/<?=$link['url'];?>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><?=$item['title'];?><span class="caret"></span></a>
                                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        <?php
                                              foreach($item['submenu'] as $submenu)
                                              {
                                                if(MongoId::isValid ($submenu['task']) == 1)
                                                {
                                                  $link = self::fetch_link($submenu['task']);
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                $link = array();
                                                $link['url'] = $submenu['task'];
                                                }
                                                ?>
                                                <li
                                                <?php
                                                if(URI_1 == $link){
                                                   echo 'class="active"';
                                                }

                                                echo '><a href="//'; print SITEURL."/".$link['url']; echo'">';
                                                print $submenu['title'];
                                                echo '</a></li>';

                                              }
                                        ?>
                                        </ul>
                                </li>
                            <?php
                          }
                        }
                        ?>

                    </ul>
```

To get that to work I had to add

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .navbar-nav{
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
        float:none;
    }
}
```

However because this navbar has two UL with the second one focusing on the social networks (see below for code), I wanted it to pull-right, which without the above code works fine, but as soon as I add the above code, while the menu above does center, the social network menu gets pushed below. Which is not the feel I was hoping for.

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills navbar-right" id="socialnetwork">
          <li><a href="#"><div class="socialnetwork youtube"></div></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><div class="socialnetwork twitter"></div></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><div class="socialnetwork facebook"></div></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><div class="socialnetwork gplus"></div></a></li>
        </ul>
```

I am wondering if anyone has any solutions to my issue.

Comment: Can you post an image that shows how you want it to look like OR Plunker or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting an id or add another classname on the main menu and use that as the selector to put the styles on...

```
<nav id="myMainNav" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
```

then on your css you put this..

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    #myMainNav{
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
        float:none;
    }
}
```

If you'll notice, they both have the classname navbar-nav which means they're both affected by the styling especially the float:none which negates the pull-right